# Is it necessary to have an SSL cert for a domain that just forwards to another domain?

Tags: security, ssl, dns, forwarding

I have an application that uses account slugs for various accounts, of the format `myapplication.com/{SLUG}`, similar to how Github does it.  This domain has an SSL cert and everything is fine.

However, I have some clients who purchased domain names that they give to clients that forwards them to their account page on my application.

For instance, let's say "John Smith" purchased domain `johnsmithisawesome.com` and he sets that domain up to forward to `myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome`.  It's mostly for branding purposes, so John can give out a cool/catchy domain name to clients which eventually sends them to my application.

Note that this redirect only happens once. I am not using it as a proxy, it is just a convenience method for folks to use a catchy domain that fully redirects them to the application domain.  After that initial redirect, the client will be on the application domain and all requests go directly to the secured application, and they should not reference the insecure domain any more.

Also note that there are no security credentials being passed back/forth to the insecure domain.  If the client has to login, they are doing it directly on the application domain and are not interacting with the insecure domain at all.

The flow essentially works like this:

1. User visits `johnsmithisawesome.com` in their browser
2. DNS for `johnsmithisawesome.com` uses an HTTP REDIRECT that points to `myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome`
3. User's browser URL is now at `myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome`
4. All further requests go through `myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome`, there are no further requests going through `johnsmithisawesome.com`

I'm hoping this is explicitly clear in what I'm trying to accomplish, I know I'm not as well versed in the terminology.

Is there any security risk with not having an SSL cert on the domain that just forwards them to my application?

My assumption is it doesn't matter, because the actual application itself is protected with SSL (or TLS as the new standard), and I can't think of any security risk with using a domain to just forward, but wanted to check with some folks who know more about this than I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you will not access the forwarding domain with HTTP you will *technically* not need to have a certificate, i.e. the redirect will work. Only, when you want to access the forwarding domain with HTTPS you technically need a certificate for this domain, even if all what is done on this domain is to forward to somewhere else. Otherwise the end user will get warnings in the browser and the forwarding will not happen.

But, even if it is not technically required it might still make sense to make use of HTTPS on the forwarding domain for security reasons.

> All further requests go through myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome, there are no further requests going through johnsmithisawesome.com

Note that this is only the technical view of what works and not works.

I interpret this as there is only a single requests to the clients domain which results in a redirect to the final domain. And that no sensitive data will be shared with the clients domain but only with the final (secured) domain.

In this case the main attack vector is an man in the middle attack which changes the target of the redirect, for example from `myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome` to an attacker controlled domain and URL like `myapplication-secure.com/johnsmithisawesome`. With a properly named domain the attacker can surely trick the user into believing that he reached the proper site.

Such attack can be mitigated by protecting the redirect with HTTPS and security-wise this is the best option. But this means that the client should access the clients domain with HTTPS in the first place, because otherwise the attacker could hijack the initial request and change the redirect. If one accepts this risk and hopes that attacker is not present during the first request one might either redirect to HTTPS and add an HSTS header to enforce future use of HTTPS on the clients domain or one could make a 301 redirect to the final domain instead a 302 redirect. With 301 the browser will cache the redirect and will not ask the clients server again but go straight to the final domain on the next visit, thus bypassing an attacker which managed to intercept requests to the clients domain.

> DNS for johnsmithisawesome.com uses an HTTP REDIRECT that points to myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome

That's not how it works.

Technically DNS can not issue HTTP redirects. DNS is only used to resolves the hostname to an IP address. The HTTP server at this address then can do the redirect at the HTTP level.

Some DNS providers still offer such a HTTP redirect. But this works by resolving the hostname to an IP address the DNS provider owns and running a special HTTP server at this IP address which then does the configured HTTP redirect. Sometimes they let the customer configure if this will be a 301 or 302 redirect and sometimes not. And usually there is no way for configure a certificate in this kind of setup anyway.

Comment: If it wasn't you, I would have commented this is not true. But I often see you give very good security answers and know you understand security, so I'm more cautious. :) Why do you think SSL stripping (or something similar) is not an issue?

Comment: @GaborLengyel: I don't think that there is anything special to SSL stripping in this case, i.e. there is no additional risk due to the redirect but no reduced risk either.

Comment: OK, I see your point. The difference I think is that this way (without SSL on the redirect domain) it's impossible to implement it properly with HSTS, while if there is a cert for that too, both can send HSTS and MitM is not possible.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: Of course whenever sensitive data need to be protected HTTPS should be used and it might be useful to additionally harden HTTPS with HSTS and maybe even HPKP. But I think that this is not the point of this question. And, it depends a lot of this is just a redirect of the initial request or if every request including the one with sensitive information passes through the clients domain.

Comment: But that's the point. If it's not https on the first domain, any client pointed at the non-ssl domain cannot be protected. So it very much is specific to the problem of whether he puts a non-ssl domain in front of it or not, because that makes the difference between requests that can be made secure with HSTS and requests that can't be protected from MitM because there is no SSL on the first domain the user connects to. So yes, it's a different issue, but the spirit of the question is whether it will be the same risk (assuming the SSL site is secure otherwise), and it will not.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: With  *in front of it*  I would understand that *every* traffic gets either forwarded (reverse proxy) or redirected. In this case HTTPS should be used on the clients domain as I've argued in my answer too. But if this is only the initial request which makes a jump from the clients domain to the real HTTPS protected domain and any further traffic is only there (and thus with HTTPS protected) then I don't see that much of a problem. Which setup is actually used is unknown.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and provide additional details, I'll update the question as well.  The redirect only happens ONCE.  I'm not using an insecure domain to pass traffic through as a proxy.  When the client goes to `johnsmithisawesome.com` it should fully redirect the browser to `myapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome` and at that point all requests go directly to the secured app and none pass through the insecure domain.

Comment: @DanL: I've changed the answer to fit the edited question.

Comment: Even if there is one single request before the redirect, that's enough for the attacker. That is exactly what ssl stripping is about. As a pentester, I would still flag this as an issue. There is no difference between not having hsts on `https://yourapplication.com` or having `http://johnsmithsisawesome.com` as a first step redirect before it. It will be vulnerable to the same thing, ssl can be bypassed.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: Unless you can make the initial request from the browser https there is always the problem of the attacker hijacking this initial request. Common HSTS will not help here since it is also known only after the first response got received and thus can be manipulated by the attacker too. Preloaded HSTS will help though.

Comment: The point in hsts is that the browser will remember for the specified time. Not even a plain 'clear history' clears it. If it *ever* saw a hsts header, it will send all subsequent requests on https for say a year. That means the attacker needs to intercept the very first request ever, and that's not very easy that way.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: you are right that HSTS is harder to get rid of compared to a cached 301. But in practice the attacker can neither rely on the user clearing HSTS information nor on clearing the history since both are things the user must do explicitly and most users wont do it and will probably not even know how to do it.

Comment: One thing to note is that I can't practically stop clients from buying domains and redirecting requests to my application (white/black-listing aside).  I won't be managing the domains clients use to redirect, only the application itself.  For instance, nothing is stopping my from buying domain `abcdef.com` and redirecting all requests to `google.com`, even though I don't own Google.  The question was really to see if it's something I should ever recommend to clients, and it's sounding like I should not recommend it to them unless they also install a cert.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the short answer is yes, if you want to secure it, you need a separate SSL cert for the other domain too.

Consider the following. Alice (the enduser) enters johnsmithisawesome.com in her browser, the browser makes a request. A man-in-the-middle attacker Mallory captures the request, makes a request to `https://yourapplication.com/johnsmithisawesome`, which creates an SSL session between Mallory and your application. When Mallory receives a response, transforms all references to your application to `http://johnsmithisawesome.com` and returns the resulting (modified) page
to Alice.

What your application can see is t here was a request on https which it served, all is good. What Alice can see is she entered a domain and got the results, even the domain name in the URL bar matches what she wanted to see. What Mallory can see is all (presumably confidential) traffic between Alice and your application. The only hint for Alice is that there is no indication of SSL in the browser, but most users won't spot that.

This is called [SSL Stripping](https://avicoder.me/2016/02/22/SSLstrip-for-newbies/), and there are ready-made tools to pull this off with a few clicks. Your scenario is a little bit special compared to the original idea, but it just helps the attacker.

In fact, Mallory doesn't even need to do this. Without a certificate for johnsmithisawesome.com, Mallory can just replace the response and that's it, he doesn't need to strip SSL strictly speaking, because there wasn't any SSL. :)

This is what the [HSTS response header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet) was invented for, and should be sent by both your application and johnsmithisawesome.com during redirection.